# WPF ProgressBar not updating

Tags: wpf, user-interface, events, mvvm, progress-bar

This is casual and prototype code, hence me trying what I think should work, googling around if it doesn't, then asking here after perusing similar questions.

I have the following markup in my `Shell` view:

```
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMessage}" />
</StatusBarItem>
<Separator Grid.Column="1" />
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding StatusProgress}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="16" Width="198" />
</StatusBarItem>
```

Then in `ShellViewModel` I have the following two properties and an event handler:

```
private string _statusMessage;
public string StatusMessage
{
    get => _statusMessage;
    set => SetProperty(ref _statusMessage, value);
}    
private double _statusProgress;
public double StatusProgress
{
    get => _statusProgress;
    set => SetProperty(ref _statusProgress, value);
}

private void OnFileTransferStatusChanged(object sender, FileTransferStatusEventArgs fileTransferStatusEventArgs)
{
    StatusMessage = fileTransferStatusEventArgs.RelativePath;
    StatusProgress = fileTransferStatusEventArgs.Progress;
}
```

The event is raised periodically, i.e. every *n* iterations, from a file download helper class.

Now the strange thing is this, when the event handler updates the vm properties, on the `Shell` view, the `TextBlock` bound to `StatusMessage` updates and displays correctly, but the `ProgressBar` bound to `StatusProgress` does not, and remains blank. If I put a break-point in the event handler, I can see the `StatusProgress` property being properly updated in various values from 0 to 100, yet this does not reflect on the `ProgressBar`.

The idea of the event handler executing on another thread, which often causes UI update problems, occurred to me, but why is one UI element updating properly and the other not?

**NOTE:** I have been *monumentally* stupid and not tested the `ProgressBar` statically, i.e. just set the viewmodel's `StatusProgress` to a value and get the shell window to display, without going through the download loop. If I do this, the progress bar displays a length that more or less corresponds to its `Value` property. None of the layout change suggestions made in comments or answers changes this. Statically it is always visible and always displays a value.

**EXAMPLE:** I created a small example that believe duplicates the problem. In the example the progress bar doesn't update until the waited on task has completed, and I believe this is the case with my main question, but it was a long download, and I didn't wait for it to complete before noticing the progress bar wasn't updating.

Here is the `StatusBar` in `MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="20">
    <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding StatusProgress}" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Height="16" Width="198" />
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

With the code behind in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel => (MainWindowViewModel)DataContext;
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.Download();
}
```

And the code in the `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
private string _statusMessage = "Downloading something";
public string StatusMessage
{
    get => _statusMessage;
    set
    {
        if (value == _statusMessage) return;
        _statusMessage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private int _statusProgress;
public int StatusProgress
{
    get => _statusProgress;
    set
    {
        if (value == _statusProgress) return;
        _statusProgress = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void Download()
{
    var dl = new FileDownloader();
    dl.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        StatusProgress = args.Progress;
    };
    dl.Download();
}
```

And finally the code for `FileDownloader`:

```
public class ProgressChangedEventArgs
{
    public int Progress { get; set; }
}

public class FileDownloader
{
    public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
    public void Download()
    {            
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs{Progress = i});
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

In the example, the progress bar remains blank, until `FileDownloader` finishes its loop, and then suddenly the progress bar shows full progress, i.e. complete.

Comment: Does it look any different if you set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to the `StatusBarItem` containing `ProgressBar`?

Comment: What's the whole markup for statusbar? It should have a grid but what columns does that have? If you temporarily put a rectangle with red fill in Grid.Column="2" is that visible. Perhaps you need to set a width on your progressbar or the column it's in.

Comment: I would look closely at the threading issues, even though the message status does show. For example, the event could be raised on the UI thread at first (i.e. event.Invoke("myfile.txt", 0) is called). The subsequent calls could then be from a non-UI thread.

When a non-UI thread invokes this event, SetProperty first sets your private field. So, within the ViewModel, the field updates. Then future property reads show the expected value. But SetProperty silently fails when it invokes the binding, which is single-threaded.

Comment: BTW, I would recommend looking at await/async vs the other multithreading tools. Task.Run can be tricky for guaranteeing that callbacks happen on the non-blocked UI thread. With await/async, the whole application can conceptually be single-threaded, with the single thread starting back where it left when an await completes.

Comment: Mode=TwoWay on a progress bar? No need. Nothing smells off, so I'd recommend snagging Snoop to examine your bindings at runtime.

Comment: @mwwaters I am using async, but no other threading tools. This is because my whole infrastructure is build around using `HttpClient`, which only has async comms methods.

Comment: @Andy The status bar does contain a grid, and even when I made the width of the column for the progress bar, all I got was a grey rectangle 300 wide, but with a thin green line at the very left.

Comment: @Will I always - I don't do XAML that often - forget which direction the default binding is, so I just slapped the `Mode=TwoWay` as one of many things I tried to make the progress bar work. I will take a look with Snoop, thanks.

Comment: INPC properties can be changed from any thread. The Binding class will marshal the update for you onto the UI thread. I really don't see anything wrong here. If you see the number changing, that suggests you're not punishing the UI, a common cause of this problem. Maybe fileTransferStatusEventArgs.Progress is always 0? I'd step through the process, verify it's not 0, verify the property reads correctly, then use Snoop to verify the state of the progress bar, inc value, min/max, width & height, layout, etc. Make 0 assumptions because something weird is happening.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. Are you sure everything is set correctly, i.e. `StatusProgress` takes values in 0-100 range rather than 0-1 (that would explain the thin green line on the left)?

Comment: please provide the XAML surrounding the above sample in order to help

Comment: Give a width to your progress bar: `<ProgressBar Value="{Binding StatusProgress, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="16" Width="100"/>`.

Comment: No `Width` [reproduces your problem](https://imgur.com/hZVq10K).

Comment: With `Width` [solves your problem](https://imgur.com/AvwRvHR).

Comment: Looks clean to me. I can't quite put my finger on it, but if the `StatusProgress` is seemingly being updated properly, then I would have to blame the notification to the UI. Try tossing in a (yes, redundant, and depricated (depending on the framework)) call to `OnPropertyChanged()` If it changes nothing then you've ruled out pretty much everything except a threading issue.

Comment: Since `DataBindEngine` works fine with multi-threading, I think is highly like that there's a simpler problem was happenning. Maybe you should

 1. Comfirm that if `ProgressBar.Value` realy wasn't changed through `ProgressBar.ValueChanged` event.
 2. If result of 1. is positive at least twice, then comfirm that `fileTransferStatusEventArgs.Progress` has changed every time, and `fileTransferStatusEventArgs.Progress` has the value of your exptation.
 3. If result of 1. is negative, comfirm that accessing `fileTransferStatusEventArgs.Progress` would cause any exception.

Comment: When `Width` is "missing", [the problem described by the OP](https://imgur.com/hZVq10K) happens even if `StatusProgress` is in the UI thread (or has been properly handled otherwise). And, assigning `Width` with a suitable value, as we suggested before, [solves the problem](https://imgur.com/AvwRvHR) in both cases, for `StatusProgress` updates in the UI thread or not.

Comment: I added `Width` at the first comment that suggested it, but forgot to update the markup in the question. The question's markup is now up to date, and the progress bar still doesn't work.

Comment: In your edited question, you block the UI thread with `FileDownloader#Download` method. Can you show your actual downloader code which raises `FileTransferStatusChanged` event? Does that have the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

### What's happening

Anything that is not about UI should be done in tasks, because, if not, you're blocking the UI thread and the UI.
In your case, the download was happening on you UI thread, the latter was waiting for the download to finish before updating your UI.

### Solution

You need to do **two things** to solve your problem:

1. remove the work from the UI thread.
2. make sure the work can communicate with you UI thread.

So, first, start the download work as a `Task` like this:

```
private ICommand _startDownloadCommand;
public ICommand StartDownloadCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _startDownloadCommand ?? (_startDownloadCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                   s => { Task.Run(() => Download()); },
                   s => true));
    }
}
```

and connect the button to the command like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartDownloadCommand}" Content="Start download" Height="20"/>
```

Then have you download method as such:

```
public void Download()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusMessage = "download started";  });

    var dl = new FileDownloader();
    dl.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusProgress = args.Progress; });
    };
    dl.Download();

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusMessage = "download DONE";  });
}
```

The dispatch will have your property (on UI thread) updated from a *non UI thread*.

And yet, the `DelegateCommand` helper class:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null) {}

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
        Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

### Remarks

In order to implement the MVVM pattern I had this code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : IView
{
    public IViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (IViewModel)DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}

public interface IViewModel {}

public interface IView {}
```

and this View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel,
            IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
```

and this ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because `StatusBarItem` default style sets its `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Left`, which leads `ProgressBar` to get only a small amount of space horizontally.

You can make the `ProgressBar` to fill the `StatusBarItem` completely by setting `StatusBarItem`'s `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` or you can set the `Width` of the `ProgressBar`.

Comment: Please see my edit. The `ProgressBar` displays without having to set that `HorizontalContentAlignment`.

Comment: Yes, because your edit now includes `Width` attribute. I prefer setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` in `StatusBarItem` instead of static `Width` in `ProgressBar`, because now you have two places where static width is defined (`GridColumn` and `ProgressBar`).

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar is a DispatcherObject, and [DispatcherObject can be only accessed by the Dispatcher it is associated with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2).

If I understand your question well your OnFileTransferStatusChanged is being triggered on a background thread, so since you're not accessing controls using a Dispatcher (or from the UI thread) you're not guaranteed that the code will work.

The problem is that binding from a non-UI thread usually works until it doesn't - e.g. on a non-dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

like first answer
be sure to be on the main UI thread, because OnFileTransferStatusChanged is on another thread. use this in your event

```
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(prio, (ThreadStart)(() => 
{
   StatusMessage = fileTransferStatusEventArgs.RelativePath;
    StatusProgress = fileTransferStatusEventArgs.Progress;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes to your sample as your file downloaded is working on UI thread and application just freezes you can see it by changing focus to other application and trying to get back - window will not appear nor update.

changes:

```
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ViewModel.Download());
 }
```

forces download to execute in new thread.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; }
```

removed cast and access to UI thread only property `DataContext`. 
Now I can see progress bar [filling up](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oh7howao75llcad/MainWindow%205_9_2018%2012_55_11%20PM.mp4?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

You can't see any changes because your Main thread AKA **UI Thread** is busy Sleeping
and it does not have time to update your UI
[image: Main Thread]

Let Task handle your lengthy job and Main thread for Updating UI

Wrap your code inside Task and you can see your progress bar progressing.

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
           _viewModel.Download();
       });
            //_viewModel.Download(); //this will run on UI Thread

 }
```